# What kinds of type is better for get the path String?

Tags: java

I want to get the String value about path.

I have two way about that.

1. Using String.format()

```
String a = "/root"
String b = "Downloads"    
String path = String.format("%s/%s",a,b)
```

2. Using Paths.get()

```
String a = "/root"
String b = "Downloads"    
String path = Path.get(a,b).toString();
```

Which one is better?
or
Do you have more better practice?

Comment: For one, `Paths.get` will use the OS's path separator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Paths.get` verifies that you pass in syntactically valid file paths. For example, on Unix you get an exception from:

```
Paths.get("a", "b\000") // -> java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Nul character not allowed
```

It also gets rid of extra directory separators:

```
Paths.get("a/", "/b") // -> a/b
```

If this behavior is what you want, use `Paths.get`.

If you just want to concatenate with no extra checks, use `String.format`.

Comment: then, When I want to use just kinds of path shape, String.format
&
I want to use path & Exception, Paths.get 

Right?

Comment: Yes that's what I would recommend

Answer (score 0):

Best util for path is:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
// Example 1
Path p = Paths.get("/articles/folder");
// Example 2
Path p2 = Paths.get("/articles", "folder");
```

For more info see [Path Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)

Comment: just will use String?

Comment: For only String used **String path = Paths.get("/articles", "folder").toString();**

Comment: How about Joni's Answer? Could you tell me about Path is more better?